# Writingad strings from parent process into the stdin of child process

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, pipe

I am trying to write two strings 'username' and 'passwd' into my child process as stdin, and run 'checker' to varify the username/passwd combo and return a value back to the parent process. Somehow my code doesn't work because "the checker program could not read from stdin" How should I fix this?

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
int fd[2];

pid = fork(); 
if ((pipe(fd)) ==-1){
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Unless you have a new-line embedded in the username and password strings, you are sending the two strings without delimeters so the child process cannot tell when each ends. You should add write(fd[1], '\n', 1); after each write call. You should also check the return value from all calls to check for errors.

Comment: @DoxyLover I have changed to write 10 bytes to stdin for both username and passwd, and my checker program would read 10 bytes at a time twice. But still getting same errors..

Comment: @user3300198 You could use the example in [this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) as a start point.